# How to convert CSV to XML with Mapforce and Mule

Tags: java, xml, csv, mule

I have generated a java transform with Mapforce from CSV to XML and I'd like to use it with Mule but I don't know how.

The Mapforce IDE generates a console app that calls the transform and it looks like below but I can't figure out how to us this transform in a mule flow.

Can you?

INPUT CSV:

```
"";"208556";"ABC123";"HASK";46;"2659307019";"MMM505";15000.00;10000.00;"160100";"Beh. avg. Brännbart avfall";"1000040";"Svensk Säkerhetsvideo AB";"Nytorpsvägen 4";"20161101";"122739"
```

and output XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<uppdrag xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:/Users/CLAES/SkyDrive/HANSAN~1/INTEGRATIONSPROJEKT/SkövdeIntegration/TESTDATA/20161031-1.xsd">
<kund>208556</kund>
<littra>1000040</littra>
<Arb_plats_ID>HASK</Arb_plats_ID>
<transaktionsid>46</transaktionsid>
<viktin>15000</viktin>
<viktut>10000</viktut>
<fraktion_ID>160100</fraktion_ID>
<fraktion_namn/>
<datum>20161101</datum>
<tid>122739</tid>
<regnr>ABC123</regnr>
```

JAVA Class from Mapforce:

```java
public class MappingConsole {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Mapping Application");

        try { // Mapping
            TraceTargetConsole ttc = new TraceTargetConsole();

            MappingMapTo20161031_1 MappingMapTo20161031_1Object = new MappingMapTo20161031_1();

            MappingMapTo20161031_1Object.registerTraceTarget(ttc);

            {
                com.altova.io.Input Text_file2Source = com.altova.io.StreamInput.createInput("C:/Users/CLAES/SkyDrive/Hans Andersson/INTEGRATIONSPROJEKT/Sk\u00F6vdeIntegration/Datamodell/textfil med rubriker.txt");
                com.altova.io.Output Name20161031_12Target = new com.altova.io.FileOutput("C:/Users/CLAES/SkyDrive/Hans Andersson/INTEGRATIONSPROJEKT/Sk\u00F6vdeIntegration/TESTDATA/20161031-1.xml");

                MappingMapTo20161031_1Object.run(
                        Text_file2Source,
                        Name20161031_12Target);
            }
            System.out.println("Finished");
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an example for both the input CSV and the required output XML.

Comment: I have now updated the question with input CSV and output XML.

Answer (score 0):

Take the java code from your main method and use it in a custom java transformer. Details on creating custom Java transformers available in the docs such as here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/creating-custom-transformer-classes

Comment: I've tried to fugure out how to pass the incomming file to the java transformer and how to return the XML from the transformer. The main uses files but how to handle mule messages?